# Can we update the data in the view

Tags: sql-server

1. Can we update the data in the view.If so, will it reflect the data in the actual table.
2. Can we delete the table if the view created on that table exists.?

Could any one explain me the above stuff. I am confused with above concepts.

Comment: why not create a test database containing a test table and view? Then you can answer your own question.

Comment: @Mitch wheat : i am still in learning stage. so, which makes me ask questions which looks simpler for others.

Comment: @Shine: Mitch means that *you* should upvote answers that you found helpful. It's easy: Just click on the up arrow of the big number next to an answer that you found helpful.

Comment: @Heinzi : oki :-) Thanks alot Heinzi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. A view *always* reflects underlying table data. There are rules and exceptions for updating via views, so see "Updatable Views" in [CREATE VIEW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx)
2. Yes. To prevent this, use WITH SCHEMABINDING in the view (see link above)

Comment: @Mitch Wheat : I see your comment above. At least they accept some which is better than many. ta :-)